# Navigation Drawer блокировка бокового меню

Tags: android, java

Есть приложение, в котором используется Navigation Drawer. Теперь вопрос: как в Navigation Drawer временно заблокировать возможность открывать боковое меню, а потом из фрагмента возобновить эту возможность?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При создании `ActionBarDrawerToggle` можно обработчик навесить свой типо такого:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(activity, mDrawerLayout,
                main ? R.drawable.action_bar_drawer_deffault: R.drawable.action_bar_drawer_arrow, R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);

            }
            private boolean back = false;
            @Override 
            public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState){

                // проверка доступности меню
                if(!isMenuActive()){

                    if(!back){
                        back = true;
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    }
                    else
                        back = false;
                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView,float slideOffset){

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };
```

А внутри метода `isMenuActive()` возвращайте статус меню, активным хотите, чтоб было, или нет.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, положим, можно задать какую-нить переменную, кою проверять в методе-слушателе открытия этого самого Navigation Drawer...